# Map Graticule in UTM projections (openlayers)

Tags: openlayers, utm, grids-graticules

I'd like to know if there is a way to display the [Graticule](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/graticule.html) labels on a different projection like UTM.

Visit [this link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/reprojection-by-codegraticule-74zd4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and search for EPSG: "**31982**" (UTM 22s SIRGAS2000) projection to understand the issue.

[image]
See the EPSG:3857 degrees coordinates at the image above.

This is what I want to display:

[image]

The decimal values for each line that comes from the UTM projection.

My code is here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/reprojection-by-codegraticule-74zd4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: The OpenLayers graticule only displays Latitude and Longitude degrees.  There are third party alternatives which can display graticules for other projections e.g. https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.control.graticule.htm

Comment: The OpenLayers graticule can display a Lat Lon graticule when the view is in another projection but that projection must be defined with a suitable extent and world extent e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/sphere-mollweide.html

Comment: There is error in link to `ol-ext` extension `ol.control.Graticule` (missing l at the end). Correct link is https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.control.graticule.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the code to

```
  // very approximate calculation of projection extent
  var worldExtent = [bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3], bbox[0]];
  newProj.setWorldExtent(worldExtent);
  var extent = applyTransform(worldExtent, fromLonLat);
  newProj.setExtent(extent);
```

will prevent the errors  https://codesandbox.io/s/reprojection-by-codegraticule-5ujx2

The graticule is designed to show lines and labels only for WGS84 Latitude and Longitude